# Import error: No module named 'boto', but i have it installed

Tags: python-3.x, boto, gcloud

I'm setting up a new functionality in mi gcloud buckets that allows me to upload or download files using a python library called "boto", but appears this error

I am using linux, visual studio code, python 3.7, gsutil and boto in their last versions.

```
import os
import boto
import gcs_oauth2_boto_plugin
import shutil
import io
import tempfile
import time
import sys



# Activate virtual environment
activate_this = os.path.join(VENV + 'bin/activate_this.py')
exec(open(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this)))


# Check arguments
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  print ("Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + ' FILENAME')
  quit()

filename = sys.argv[1]

# URI scheme for Cloud Storage.
GOOGLE_STORAGE = "gs"
# URI scheme for accessing local files.
LOCAL_FILE = "file"

header_values = {"x-goog-project-id": PROJECT_ID}

# Open local file
with open(filename, 'r') as localfile:

  dst_uri = boto.storage_uri(BUCKET + '/' + filename, GOOGLE_STORAGE)
  # The key-related functions are a consequence of boto's
  # interoperability with Amazon S3 (which employs the
  # concept of a key mapping to localfile).
  dst_uri.new_key().set_contents_from_file(localfile)

print ('Successfully created "%s/%s"' % (dst_uri.bucket_name, dst_uri.object_name))
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./upload2gcs.py", line 10, in 
    import boto
ImportError: No module named boto

Comment: I assume this file is "upload2gcs.py", but there is nothing on line 10. Is that where your "import boto" statement is in the real file?

Comment: try "import .boto"

Answer (score 0):

The directory containing the boto module probably isn't findable from any of the paths where Python looks for modules to be imported.

From within your script, check the `sys.path` list and see if the expected directory is present:

```
import pprint
import sys

pprint.pprint(sys.path)
```

As an example, gsutil is packaged with its own fork of Boto; it performs some additional steps at runtime to make sure the Boto module's parent directory is added to `sys.path`, which allows subsequent `import boto` statements to work:
[https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/c74a5964980b4f49ab2c4cb4d5139b35fbafe8ac/gslib/**init**.py#L102](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/c74a5964980b4f49ab2c4cb4d5139b35fbafe8ac/gslib/__init__.py#L102)

Comment: Thanks, i will test this and let you a comment if the solution fix my problem.